# How do i install drivers for Lexmark Z1300 printer for ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: drivers, printing, lexmark

I bought a new Lexmark Z1300 printer, I couldn't find any drivers for linux for this series, Is there any way to install drivers and make use of this printer on ubuntu 13.10 or i have to switch back to windows to take the printouts?

Answer (score 0):

Install the common printer driver packages in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client cups-common cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debconf ghostscript libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libc-bin libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libusb-1.0-0 lsb-base poppler-utils procps
```

Then use the printer with the application `system-config-printer-gnome`

Comment: That is not going to work.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks to pointout. why it is so? I can change the answer.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package cups-core-drivers

Comment: Because there is no cups driver that will work for the z3100. Lexmark had zero support for Linux.

Comment: what should i do now? @BillGates

Comment: Error:  0: couldn't open source file <procps.ui>
procps.ui: No such file or directory
@BillGates

Comment: I removed the unavailable package. give a try with the rest. If it doesnt works you are in a problematic situation as Rinzwind stated.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubutuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49714) has a list of Lexmark printers that worked in 2007(!) based of a Gentoo article. Back then Lexmark provided a z600 driver but that has been removed from their site. You can try to follow this installation for your z3100 but the 1st mentioning of this printer is post 320 and states it does not work.

My personal experience: in relation to Ubuntu the cheaper Lexmark printers tend to be paperweights. I have only managed to use Lexmark printers when I could hook them up on the network. Not direct from Ubuntu.

You will save yourself a lot of trouble if you return the printer and get a supported one (all HP printers work out of the box)